# PyQt intercept close event without inheritance

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a socket based program. In order to close the connection in a graceful manner on the client side, I have to handle the close event. However, all closing event codes I have seen in the site were written using OOP. As most of my script (a very long one) is written using a procedural paradigm, I've tried to implement those codes but couldn't get it work. How can I solve this?

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

v_box = QVBoxLayout()

window = QWidget()
label = QLabel("Hello World")

v_box.addWidget(label)

def closeEvent(event):
    choice = QMessageBox.question( "Quit", "Do you want to quit chit chat?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
        s.close()
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

app.aboutToQuit.connect(closeEvent)
window.setLayout(v_box)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional programming. What you are doing is called procedural programming. I have updated your question ;)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my conceptual confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to intercept the close event of your window, not the application. One way to do it is by creating a class that inherits from `QWidget` or `QMainWindow` and override `closeEvent`, if you don't want to use classes, you can use `functools` like in the following example:

```
import functools
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QMessageBox


def closeEvent(self, event):
    choice = QMessageBox.question(self, "Quit", "Do you want to quit chit chat?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

v_box = QVBoxLayout()

window = QWidget()

window.closeEvent = functools.partial(closeEvent, window)

label = QLabel("Hello World")

v_box.addWidget(label)

window.setLayout(v_box)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I didn't know that self can also be used in procedural programming.