# Intercepting QDialog closeEvent with functools takes extra argument

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to intercept the closeEvent from a QDialog just like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540934/pyqt-intercept-close-event-without-inheritance). I used `functools.partial` to call another function inside an object.

```
class BrowserDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BrowserDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Browser:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""
    def __init__(self, iface):
        ...

    def close_event(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.dlg = BrowserDialog()
        self.dlg.closeEvent = functools.partial(self.close_event)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: close_event() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What extra arugument am I giving?

Comment: As suggested by the accepted answers, it's better to avoid overwriting like this, *but* in any case, there's an easy solution to understand what's wrong: just add arguments to the function, and then print them: `def close_event(self, *args): print(args)`. Also, in this specific situation, there's really no need for partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not make `foo_object.barEvent = some_function` since that method can fail since PyQt has a cache of those methods so your assignment can be ignored, on the other hand the closeEvent method receives a parameter that gives the information of the event. Instead of doing this it is better to create a signal that is the most optimal way to invoke functions in Qt, that signal must be emitted override the closeEvent method.

```py
class BrowserDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BrowserDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super(BrowserDialog, self).closeEvent(event)
        self.closed.emit()


class Browser:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""
    def __init__(self, iface):
        ...

    def handle_closed(self):
        print("closed")

    def run(self):
        self.dlg = BrowserDialog()
        self.dlg.closed.connect(self.handle_closed)
```